# What is this little black box and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, embedded, framebuffer

I built an application using Qt 5.2 for my TI AM335x EVM and it’s showing a little black box (see image below).

It looks like a highlighted cursor, when I touch any place on the screen it flashes (about once per touch). If it is a cursor.. I don’t want it there (there’s no mouse/keyboard with my project, just touch screen) so how do I get rid of it?

I know it has to be something with how my environment is configured because more than one of my projects is showing the same little black box in the same location.

This is the command I used to configure my environment:

> ./configure -prefix /usr/Qt5.2 -xplatform linux-am335x-g++ -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-glib -no-cups -no-largefile -no-accessibility -no-openssl -no-gtkstyle -opensource

Image of the black box:
[image]

Comment: What technology are you using for graphical display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is unrelated to Qt after all.

It turns out [the framebuffer console (fbcon)](http://free-electrons.com/kerneldoc/latest/fb/fbcon.txt) was running on my board. There is a [cursor_blink](http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=FrameBuffer) setting for the fbcon and it needed to be set to 0 in order to not see the cursor show up.

I thought it was related to Qt version because when I was running the Qt4 application from TI I didn't see this, but it turns out they ran a script first disabling this.

By adding the following:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

Into my init.d script, I was able to get rid of the cursor.